# Verifying calls for unmocked object in Java/Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have this class:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class CompliledPatterns {
   private static final Map<String, Pattern> compiledPatterns = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

   public static Pattern getPattern(String regex) {
       Pattern pattern = null;
       if (regex != null) {
           pattern = compiledPatterns.get(regex);
           if (pattern == null) {
               pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
               compiledPatterns.putIfAbsent(regex, pattern);
           }
       }
       return pattern;
   }
}
```

Now I want to write test cases for this. What are the possible test cases for this?

What if a duplicate regex is passed to the getPattern() metthod in test class, Is there any way to verify calls?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: you don't need any mock. You need to check that getting a pattern for a regex that you've never passed gives you a new compiled pattern, and that getting a pattern for a regex you have already passed gives you the same compiled pattern. Your code doesn't compile. You should fix that first. Then use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function- to make your code more correct.

Comment: Unrelated: I would recommend to rather throw an exception when the incoming string is null or empty; instead of returning null. Returning null is always the first step to run into a NullPointerException. Null patterns dont make sense, so **do not** allow null pattern strings! Force the caller to think about the values that get passed into this method!

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. One additional thing: be a bit careful about using such caches. Yes, compiling patterns might be expensive. But assuming that this method is called very often - understand that a only-growing map can result in a memory leak! In case your application is supposed to run indefinitely, you have to clear the cache periodically. Or even more complicated : invalidate entries sometimes!

Comment: Correct. Agree on this point. Clearing cache would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **contract** of this class is: you provide patterns as string, and the class caches the compiled patterns. So focus on testing the **contract**, not a specific **implementation** (that happens to use a map).

Like in:

- first you write tests for translating strings to patterns: you push in null, empty, "simple" strings; and then you check for the expected result result
- and for the caching part: use `==` to check for equal references of patterns!

In other words: you want to test that the method returns **the same** pattern when pushing **equal** strings. So you can do something like:

```
@Test
public void testCachig() {
  Pattern first = CompliledPatterns.getPattern("whatever");
  Pattern second = CompliledPatterns.getPattern("whatever");
  assertThat(first, isSame(second));
}
```

*isSame()* is a hamcrest matcher checking for refential equality; in other words; you `assertThat(first == second, is(true))` here.

You want to **avoid** inspecting the inner state of that class. This is an implementation detail. You only care about the **same** object being returned.

How that is achieved should *not* be visible in your test case. Because then you are free to change that implementation, without the need to change the test case! And surprise: that thing works completely without using mocking frameworks!

And I agree with davidxxx: *static* is an abnormality in good OO. It leads to tight coupling and kills polymorphism. Only use it if you have good reasons to do so.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat for the approach! :)

Comment: You are welcome. Just don't forget to accept the answer you found the most helpful in the end.

Comment: @davidxxx Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

With `static` modifier for methods to test, you will have difficulty to set the context in a natural way for all tests.
As the class is loaded once, you will keep the context between your test methods.
And you need to set the context as your class has a state : the `compiledPatterns Map` field.

First step : remove the static modifiers

```
private final Map<String, Pattern> compiledPatterns = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public Pattern getPattern(String regex) {
   Pattern pattern = null;
   if (regex != null) {
       pattern = compiledPatterns.get(regex);
       if (pattern == null) {
           pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
           compiledPatterns.putIfAbsent(regex, pattern);
       }
   }
   return pattern;
}
```

Second step : to unit test, you have to know the state of the object under test.
After invoking the `getPattern()` method, you should have a way to inspect the content of the `compiledPatterns Map` field to know if your implementation has performed which it should do.

To achieve it, you could provide a view (unmodifiable map) backed to the `compiledPatterns Map` field.

```
public Map<String, Pattern> compiledPatterns getCompiledPatternsView(){
   return Collections.unmodifiableMap(compiledPatterns);
}
```

And in assertion, use it.

For example for this base scenario : when a regex is passed for the first time, it is cached in the map.

The test method could be for example :

```
@Test
public void getPattern_with_first_time_passed_caches_and_returns_the_pattern(){
   CompliledPatterns compliledPatterns = new CompliledPatterns();
   String regex = "\\s+\\d+";
   Assert.assertTrue(compliledPatterns.getCompiledPatternsView().isEmpty());
   // action
   compliledPatterns.getPattern(regex); 
   //assertion
   Assert.assertEquals(1, compliledPatterns.getCompiledPatternsView().size());    
   Assert.assertEquals(regex, compliledPatterns.getCompiledPatternsView().get(regex).pattern());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @David for immediate answer! :)

Comment: @GhostCat The static part is indeed a real problem as the class has a state. But about the way to assert, thank you for your remark. You are really right.